# Django Forms: Don't upload new file on edit. Conditional logic

Tags: django, forms

I HAVE scoured the web and if there is a solution I have not found it. Perhaps the answer is right in front of me but I don't see it and I'm really baffled at this issue.

**Problem:** I have a model:

```
class Campaign(models.Model):

    emailaddress = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='', verbose_name='ADF Email', blank=True)
    xlsfile = models.FileField(upload_to='xlsfiles/', blank=True, null=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    dealerimage = models.ForeignKey('vipapp.savedImage', blank=True, null=True, related_name='campaign')
```

I do not override the `admin` add/change form currently. Perhaps I should, we'll see.

When I submit a new campaign an `xlsfile` and `dealerimage` are uploaded and should be required. I use if(`self.xlsfile`): in the overridden `save()` on the campaign model to check for the optional `xlsfile` and if it exists I have a considerable amount of code that parses the `xlsfile`, puts the records into another model called `weblist` and also sends the user a modified excel file (I am using both **xlsfile** and **excel file** naming on purpose in this post).

**The problem is this:** When the user edits a campaign using the default `admin` change form the excel file is listed in the `xlsfile` field. On submit, the system appears to try again to upload the excel file and that file may no longer actually exist on the system from which the user is editing. On edit, the user may not want to upload a new excel file as this would overwrite the other model (`weblist`).

**Question:** How would I clear this field in the change form yet not delete it from the object when the user submits? I cannot use exclude because the user MAY want to upload a new excel file.

**Question:** What is `self.xlsfile` in the `save()` on the campaign model? I mean, how do I tell the difference between what is in the database already (maybe `obj.xlsfile`) and what is coming in from the change form `POST`? Is new data in the post `self.xlsfile` or is that what is in the object already? I know I should be able to determine these things on my own but I've not been able to reliable tell if my test is correct so that it gives me the correct answer.

How do I effectively clear the field when the form loads? The user MAY want to replace the `xls` and therefore delete the `weblist` records but this is not typical. Replacing the `weblist` instances in the `weblist` model is **dangerous** because these contain generated codes that have already been sent to customers so this rarely happens, so if there is no new excel file the `weblist` instances should not be touched. If the user does upload a new excel file the current `weblist` instances should be deleted and re-written however.

exclude on the edit form is not an option because again, `xlsfile` may sometimes need to be updated though this is rare. I don't want to delete anything, but I don't want the form to show the `xls` file or make any changes unless the user explicitly uploads a new `xlsfile`. I may have repeated myself here but I just want to be clear.

I suspect the answer here will affect the `dealerimage` field as I will probably understand this better in general. Any explanatory info here would be awesome. Also, providing me links to **Working with Forms** or **The Forms API** or **Form and field Validation** pages will likely be unhelpful as I have read these documents. Pointing to an exact answer that I may have missed in those pages however may provide an Ah-ha moment though :)

Comment: *"On submit, the system appears to try again to upload the excel file and that file may no longer actually exist."* This is not standard behaviour. Are you absolutely sure that this is what happens, and if so, what error do you get that confirms this?

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out...

I just overrode get_form so that xlsfile field would always be set to blank on load of my CampaignEditForm:

```
def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
    if obj:
        obj.xlsfile = ''
        kwargs['form'] = CampaignEditForm
    else:
        kwargs['form'] = CampaignAddForm

    return super(campaignAdmin, self).get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)
```

Then in the save() of my campaign model I just explicitly set the fields I wanted to save, leaving out xlsfile if it was blank so any value in the DB never got deleted unless it was replaced:

```
if self.xlsfile:
    super(Campaign, self).save(*args,**kwargs)
else:
    super(Campaign, self).save(update_fields=["dealername", "campaignname", "dealeraddress", "dealercity",
                                              "dealerstate", "dealerzipcode", "dealerphone", "dealeremail1",
                                              "dealeremail2", "dealeremail3", "dealeremail4", "dealeremail5",
                                              "adf", "adfemail", "created", "dealerimage"])
```